# I can not build some xcode project

Tags: iphone, xcode

I downloaded some open source program from here
https://github.com/indisoluble/Barcode-Reader

And I tried to build it but I couldnot

Error message was this
"There is no SDK with specified name or path '/Developer_Xcode3/SKDs/IceTouch-1.1/iphonesimulator.sdk"

I do not understand the meaning of it and do not know how to handle this.

Could you tell me a solution please?

Answer (score 0):

Select the root level of the project, in "Groups & Files". It's blue. Then hit command-I to get its Info.

Pick "Build" from the segmented controller at the top of the info window. In the first section of that panel you'll see Base SDK as one of the first few lines of options. Select the latest version of the SDK you find in there, and close the window to save your options.

Build-and-run the project, it should work.

Comment: latest version of the SDK is iphone simulater 4.0.     Do I need to update it??